# Can’t log into my 2017 macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, error, login-screen

I can not log into my mac, it stops here after I enter the password, i have tried restarting it more than 10 times but it still stays here after I entered the password. I tried reinstalling the os, everything was fine, reinstall successfully, but then it keeps stopping here after i enter the password
[image]

Comment: Do you have a recent backup of all your data?

Comment: Have you tried to hold down the shift key while starting up? This will start thee computer in safe mode.